# jQuery AJAX call on NodeJS and mysql (POST req) for dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, ajax, post

I tried to get a dependent drop-down list from `MySQL` database in `Node.js`.

I searched a lot in the Internet for dependent drop-down list, but nothing is there for `Node.js` all is with `PHP` only.

HTML

```
<label class="field" >Site</label>
<select name="site" id="dropdown" >
    <option value="">- select -</option>
</select>
<label class="field" >Block</label>
<select name="block" id="dropdown1" >
    <option value="">- select -</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/site_name",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){

            var len = data.length;

            console.log(data);
            $("#dropdown").empty();
            for(var i =0; i<len;i++){
            var value1 = data[i]['site_name'];
            var value2 = data[i]['site_id'];
                $("#dropdown").append("<option value='"+value2+"' >"+value1+"</option>");

            }
        }
    });
}); 

    $("#dropdown").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/block_name",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){

            var len = data.length;

            console.log(data);
            $("#dropdown1").empty();
            for(var i =0; i<len;i++){
            var value1 = data[i]['block_name'];
            var value2 = data[i]['block_id'];
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value='"+value2+"' >"+value1+"</option>");

            }
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

IN SERVER.JS

```
app.get('/block_name', function (req,res){

    //var id=  req.body.site;
    var sql='SELECT  `block_name`,`block_id` FROM `tbl_block` ';
    connection.query(sql,function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: so which part of your code is causing a problem? You have described your requirements but not what issue exactly you are facing. One obvious thing that might be a problem is that, if the dropdowns are meant to be dependent, you never send the value of the first dropdown to the block_name server method, and the query takes no account of it. So the values will never change based on the selection. You need to send the value of `dropdown` to the server, and then use it in your SQL query to restrict the results.

Comment: @ADyson crctly you observed what i ment ask . but i dont know how to send the first value of dropdown to the server and to execute the query

Comment: I'm sure you can google how to send a variable via jQuery ajax, and also how to receive a request variable in nodeJS and process it? This is a generic procedure, you don't need to restrict your search to examples specific to dropdowns. Did you search for this kind of thing?

Comment: @ADyson i searched a lot but i didn't found anything pls suggest some link or do some changes in my code i really need it

Comment: Your searches can't have been too good then. Try this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&q=jquery+ajax+send+GET+variable&oq=jquery+ajax+send+GET+variable&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1l2j0i8i13i30k1.2212.2581.0.2702.4.4.0.0.0.0.136.136.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.135.qZ-40FdGzA0 for sending variables with $.ajax

Comment: and search "node js read get parameters" to find lots of examples for the server side (link is too long to post in comments). Try something from those. If you still can't make it work, edit the question with your attempted code and any errors you're getting, then we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/block_name/:id', function (req,res){

    //var id=  req.body.site;
    var sql='SELECT  `block_name`,`block_id` FROM `tbl_block` where id = req.params.id ';
    connection.query(sql,function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are _better than nothing_, but answers are far more useful if a description of the code is included, explaining why it solves the asker's issue. ;)